# Clustering of Graph with Binary Vertex Labels

Tags: algorithm, clustering, graphs

Consider a graph data structure with unweighted edges, where each vertex has been assigned either 0 or 1.

I am wondering if there exists a good way of clustering this graph to detect communities. All nodes within a community should be connected. A community could contain both 0 and 1, but one of the two labels should be dominating. It should ideally also be densely connected within each community, and sparsely connected between communities. It should be possible to detect more than 2 communities from the structure.

The graph clustering algorithms that I have found works with the edge weights. So a more open, general question would be if there exist any nice algorithms that work with vertex labels rather than edge weights?